# Power Query to sum for each color and each size, return a value on the available size list

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a list of shirt colors and the suggested sizes of them. I would like to create a new column in the query and have a value of list based on the filtered elements ( I have no idea how to explain it differently, feel free to correct me).
 So the rules are:

1. If the current color has XS in the occurrence list then the value of the row needs to be "YES"
2. If the current color does not have XS but has XXL,XL or L then the value should be "XYES"
3. Otherwise the value needs to be "NO"

| Jacket Color | Jacket Size |
| --- | --- |
| Black | XS |
| Black | XS |
| Black | S |
| Blue | XS |
| Blue | L |
| Blue | XL |
| Blue | XXL |
| Blue | XL |
| Blue | XXL |
| Green | XS |
| Green | S |
| Green | M |
| Red | XS |
| Red | XXL |
| Red | S |
| Red | XXL |
| White | S |
| White | M |

The table should look like this:

| Jacket Color | Jacket Size | New_col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Black | XS | YES |
| Black | XS | YES |
| Black | S | YES |
| Blue | XS | XYES |
| Blue | L | XYES |
| Blue | XL | XYES |
| Blue | XXL | XYES |
| Blue | XL | XYES |
| Blue | XXL | XYES |
| Green | XS | YES |
| Green | S | YES |
| Green | M | YES |
| Red | XS | XYES |
| Red | XXL | XYES |
| Red | S | XYES |
| Red | XXL | XYES |
| White | S | NO |
| White | M | NO |

I am not that big of a tech guy myself, if you can help me how to google the answer, that is good aswell.
Thank you in advance.

Tried everything I could with this little knowledge I have about power query. If this could be solved by me, I would have a job right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your result data doesn't match your sample data but this is the process.

1. Import data in PQ

[image]

2. Select Jacket Color and then group by from the ribbon. Enter the following:

[image]

3. Add a new custom column from the ribbon and enter the following:

   if List.Contains([All][Jacket Size], "XS") then "Yes" else if  List.ContainsAny([All][Jacket Size], {"XXL","XL", "L"}) then "XYES" else "No"

[image]

4. Expand the column to get all rows back.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I liked yours better.

Comment: You gotta be a power query shihan or something higher! I have no words, this is the answer I was looking for. Huge thanks! <3